# What is difference between mysqli_fetch_array and MYSQLI_BOTH?

Tags: php, mysqli

I know that

```
mysqli_fetch_assoc,
mysqli_fetch_array,
mysqli_fetch
```

However, is `MYSQLI_BOTH` equal to `mysqli_fetch_array` or are they in fact different?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From the PHP Manual:

> By using the MYSQLI_ASSOC constant this function will behave
>   identically to the mysqli_fetch_assoc(), while MYSQLI_NUM will behave
>   identically to the mysqli_fetch_row() function. The final option
>   MYSQLI_BOTH will create a single array with the attributes of both.

These are the **optional parameters** which use to indicate what type of `array` will return.

Here is the basic examples:

```
$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);

array(
    0 => "val 1",
    1 => "val 2"
);

$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

array(
    'key0' => "val 1",
    'key1' => "val 2"
);

$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);

array(
    0 => "val 1",
    'key0' => "val 1",
    1 => "val 2",
    'key1' => "val 2"
);
```

[PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

Answer (score 7):

[mysqli_fetch_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

> function can also store the data in associative indices, using the
>   field names of the result set as keys.

**For example**

```
<?php
    mysqli_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password") or
        die("Could not connect: " . mysqli_error());
    mysqli_select_db("mydb");

    $result = mysqli_query("SELECT id, name FROM mytable");

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        printf ("ID: %s  Name: %s", $row["id"], $row["name"]);
    }

    mysqli_free_result($result);
?>
```

[MYSQLI_BOTH](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

> Will create a single array with the attributes of both.

**For example**

```
<?php
    mysqli_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password") or
        die("Could not connect: " . mysqli_error());
    mysqli_select_db("mydb");

    $result = mysqli_query("SELECT id, name FROM mytable");

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
        printf ("ID: %s  Name: %s", $row[0], $row["name"]);
    }

    mysqli_free_result($result);
?>
```

Comment: You have an error. [`mysqli_error()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) needs one argument. Please consider switching error mode on instead. [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Answer (score 6):

```
mysqli_fetch_array()
```

has second argument `$resulttype`.

There are three options:

`MYSQLI_ASSOC`, `MYSQLI_NUM`, or `MYSQLI_BOTH`.

Meanings:

`MYSQLI_ASSOC`: Fetch associative array

`MYSQLI_NUM`: Fetch numeric array

`MYSQLI_BOTH`: Fetch both associative and numeric array.

MYSQLI_BOTH is default.

if we do not provide the second parameter, `MYSQLI_BOTH` will be considered.

So, the statements:

> $result = mysqli_fetch_array($res, MYSQLI_BOTH);

AND

> $result = mysqli_fetch_array($res);

Are equal.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Answer (score 6):

`MYSQLI_BOTH` is equal to `mysqli_fetch_array`.

You want both numeric and associative array then you can use

```
mysqli_fetch_array($res);
```

OR

```
mysqli_fetch_array($res, MYSQLI_BOTH);
```

Answer (score 5):

MYSQLI_BOTH will create a single array with the attributes of MYSQLI_NUM and MYSQLI_ASSOC.

From the documentation:

> By using the MYSQLI_ASSOC constant this function will behave identically to the mysqli_fetch_assoc(), while MYSQLI_NUM will behave identically to the mysqli_fetch_row() function. The final option MYSQLI_BOTH will create a single array with the attributes of both.
>
> **Source**
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Answer (score 5):

`MYSQLI_BOTH` is an option in `mysqli_fetch_array` that allows you to access arrays in an associative way e.g. `$result['name']` and by index e.g. the number of the position in the result `$result[0]`.

Within `mysqli_fetch_array`, the second parameter allows the option for `MYSQLI_NUM` which is using the index method only, `MYSQLI_ASSOC` which you can access using the associate way and lastly `MYSQLI_BOTH` which allows you to access the values either of the way.

`mysqli_fetch_assoc()` essentially allows you to access the result using the first method `$result['name']`.

Answer (score 5):

**`mysqli_fetch_array`** — Fetch a result row as an associative, a numeric array, or both

there are two parameter in **`mysqli_fetch_array`**

1.Result

2.Result Type(Optional)

> 1.Result

A result set identifier returned by **mysqli_query(), mysqli_store_result() or mysqli_use_result().**

**example**

```
$query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER by ID LIMIT 3";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
```

> 2.Result Type

**`MYSQLI_BOTH`** - Fetch a result row as an associative and a numeric array(Default Parameter)

**example**

```
/* associative and numeric array */
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH);
printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row[0], $row["CountryCode"]);
```

**`MYSQLI_ASSOC`** - Fetch a result row as an associative array

> you can use alternative  mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) return result as a associative array

**example**

```
/* associative array */
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["Name"], $row["CountryCode"]);
```

**`MYSQLI_NUM`** - Fetch a result row as  a numeric array

**example**

```
/* numeric array */
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM);
printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row[0], $row[1]);
```

[php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

> It means there is a no comparison between `mysqli_fetch_array` and `MYSQLI_BOTH` because is a default argument of `mysqli_fetch_array`.you can compare `mysqli_fetch_array` with `mysqli_fetch_assoc`